# How to create an overflow menu (not on the toolbar) - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I understand how to create a `ToolbarItem` and set it's `Order` equal to `Secondary` which will give me an overflow menu like so:

[image]

[image]

But I'm not sure how I could implement such a menu in other parts of my application. For instance in the app I'm currently working on, I've removed the toolbar and created my own meaning there is no way to set the `ToolbarItems` property. I can add a `ImageButton` for the 3 dots overflow menu icon but I cannot get it to display a menu like the out of the box implementation does.

I'd also like to use this in other parts of my app (not just on the toolbar) such as on some sort of CardView.

Has anyone dealt with this problem before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Absolute layout to achieve this:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
   <StackLayout RowSpacing="0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
      <!--Main Content of the screen-->
   </StackLayout>
   <BoxView Color="Gray" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0,250,250" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

In the above code I have used a BoxView of Gray background for that menu toolbar to just show a demo, you can implement your view and set the width and height accordingly and make that view visible on click of icon which you will add on the toolbar.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved using AbsoluteLayout in Xamarin.Forms

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout

https://xamgirl.com/absolutelayout-in-xamarin-made-simple/